# How to change the color of icon according to user login

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have made an extension to my website.It navigates to my home page which is my login page.When the user log on to my site,the extension icon must appear green and when user log out, the icon should appear red. Please someone help me. I have been trying these two days, but I am not getting how to do it.

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "My First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extension that I made.",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

Here is my background.js file:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': "http://www.example.com"});
});
```

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Calpine Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Log on to calpinemate",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension",
        "default_icon": "calpine_not_logged_in.png"
    },

    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["http://calpinemate.com"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to communicate the login status from your webpage to your extension (as explained **[here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage)**).

---

From your webpage you have to send messages to the extension to inform it about the user's login status.

- Once the user successfully logs in, make sure you let the extension know:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      <your-extension-id>,
      {status: 'LOGGED_IN'});
  ```
- Once you detect that the user's session has ended (either expired or due to manually logging out), make sure you let the extension know:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      <your-extension-id>,
      {status: 'LOGGED_OUT'});
  ```

---

From your extension listen for messages from the webpage and update accordingly, e.g. change the extension's icon. You'll need two icons (e.g. `red.png` for indicating logged-out user and `green.png` for indicating logged-in user) and the source code below:

**background.js:**

```
var url = '<your-webpage-url>';

// Listen for external messages (messages from web-pages).
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
  if (sender.url === url) {
    // OK, this page is allowed to communicate with me.
    if (msg.status === 'LOGGED_IN') {
      // Cool, the user is logged in.
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'green.png'});
    } else if (msg.status === 'LOGGED_OUT') {
      // How sad, the user is logges out.
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'red.png'});
    }
  }
});
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name":    "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.0",

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    "default_icon": "red.png"
  },

  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["<your-webpage-url>"]
  }
}
```

Comment: But how to know if the  user is logged in or not?

Comment: In the first part of the answer, I explain how you should send a message from your webpage to the extension (informing it if the user is logged in or out). Your webpage knows whether the user is logged in or not. So, your server side code you can include a variable in the webpages JS (example "logged in" or "logged out") and when the page is rendered in the user's browser the page's JS will send a message to your extension (see code in my answer).

Comment: should i put the code you provided or should i add any extra code??

Comment: You should add the code I provided. If any extra code is needed depends on your server side code and setup (and I don't know how it looks like). If you want to somehow share your code, I will take a look.

Comment: chrome.runtime.sendMessage(<your_extension_id>, { status: "logged in" });and chrome.runtime.sendMessage(<your_extension_id>, { status: "logged out" }); should be put in background.js.right?

Comment: No, there lines have to be put on your web-page, so your web-page can inform the extension when the user is logged in or out respectively.

Comment: It is showing that "Could not load extension from '/home/uvj/Documents/sh'. Invalid match pattern 'http://calpinemate.com'"   What would be the reason?please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot debug your code if I can't see it. You have an invalid match pattern somewhere, but I cannot guess what you are doing wrong. Post some code, if you need advise on that code.

Comment: When I tried to reload the extension,the above error message was shown

Comment: I am sure it did, but I don't know what is the exact source code of your extension that you tried to reload. Unless you post some code this is the last comment from me. Sorry.

Comment: The match pattern needs a path part (even if it is 0-length). So, change your pattern to: `http://calpinemate.com/`

Answer (score 0):

U can keep 2 icon 1 in red and other in green and track session if login then show green icon else red

Comment: please explain.where should i put the code??in background.js??how can i get the session value??