# Icon color of chrome extension changes when visited specific page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have encountered some chrome extensions which changes their color of icon (possibly when activated or enabled), I don't know how it works

My question is: How can I achieve same functionality?

I mean is it because when some specific pages are visited then they get activated or is there something else.

I am confused, how does this work?

Comment: You can use chrome.browserAction API, see the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:browseraction). An alternative is chrome.declarativeContent.

Comment: take a look at the answers in this question  [Chrome Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138273/how-to-change-the-color-of-icon-according-to-user-login)

Comment: Thanks it helped..